# How to load and draw images using Java? Programming bitmapped graphics

Tags: java, bitmap

I am following a book to learn about java game programming and I got stuck here. The book is called "Beginning Java SE 6 Game Programming, Third Edition" by Jonathan S, Harbour. I need help in this specific part of the code where loading the bitmap image and getting it to load. All I get is a black Screen. I am unclear specifically on the part where it says string filename and .getResource(filename). I am still learning.

I got the image of a castle here, http://www.reinerstilesets.de/2d-grafiken/2d-buildings/

and its this one specifically http://www.reinerstilesets.de/thumbs_t/ts%20062.jpg

Please help, thank you. And if you can explain it a bit as I really want to learn this.

Heres the code,

```
//DrawImage program
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DrawImage extends JFrame {
private Image image;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DrawImage();
}

public DrawImage() {
    super("DrawImage");
    setSize(600,600);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    image = tk.getImage(getURL("castle.png"));
}

private URL getURL(String filename){
    URL url = null;
    try{
        url = this.getClass().getResource(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    return url;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //create an instance of Graphics2D
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    //fill the background with black
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);      

    //draw the image
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 40, this);
}
}
```

Comment: Two things, 1- Dont use Toolkit.getImage, it's kind of out of date. You should be using ImageIO.read instead. This can read from a file, URL and InputStream. 2- Don't override paint of a top level container like JFrame, it's not double buffered and the way you're using it means that you've broken the entire paint chain, which will come back and haunt you. Lastly, the location of the image is important. Where is the file located relative to the class file?

Comment: The file is currently located within the workspace of the program. I was unsure of where to save it to. Its in here C:\Users\Owner\workspace\DrawImage\Castle. I am pretty sure i have to put it somewhere in the program so it can access it but i tried putting it in where it says filename and nothing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Which build tool/IDE uses a *sex* directory? Must be fun working at your workplace :)

Comment: Im sorry what do you mean by sex directory? So put the image itself in the same file of the project?

Comment: @JBNizet can't believe that got past the iPads autocorrect :P

Comment: I dont see any Jar files within the workspace, I do se metadata in there. Im assuming the workspace is where the src directory is? So the code itself stays the same and wherever it says "filename" that doesnt changed then? The part where it says Castle.png  does that have anything to do with the filename? Or is that just a name being given? When I download the picture the filename starts as "T castle iso"

Comment: The src (*.java) files are built into class files (think they end up in the bin directory), if what I'm told is correct, the other files within the src file are copied to the same location as well.  These files are then, automatically, included within the class file.  When you "export" your project, it takes all these files and adds them to a Jar file.  `getResources` looks within your programs classpath for the named resource, this is also known as an embedded resource, as it, typically, resides within your code context and not externally on the file system.

Comment: Try adding the image to the root location of the `src` directory.  Also take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to put and image in a JFrame is just to wrap it in a JLabel:

```
public class MyImage{

    public BufferedImage img;

    public MyImage(String path){
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(600, 400);

        MyImage i = new MyImage("YOUR IMG PATH");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel():
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i.img));
        panel.add(label);
        window.add(panel);             
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `setBounds` AND `setSize`?  You should be calling `setVisible` last, after you've added all the content to the window, otherwise this could produce a blank screen on some systems. You should be creating your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)